# How do i use str_replace to replace 2 different words?

Tags: php, html

I want to replace these to words:
`<<abonnee>>`
and 
`<<korting>>`

`<<abonnee>>` needs to be replaced with `$abonnee`

`<<korting>>` needs to be replaced with `$korting`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="nl">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
  <body>
  <?php
   $korting=50;
   $abonnee="Jan Davids";

   $brief="
   Beste <b><<abonnee>></b><br>
   U heeft het laatste nummer van ons magazine ontvangen.<br>
   Omdat we u heel graag als abonnee willen behouden, bieden we u een 
   aantrekkelijke 
   en exclusieve korting: <br>U betaalt <<korting>> in plaats van 65 
   euro. 
   <br><br>
   <i>Profiteer nu van deze aanbieding!</i><br><br>
   Met vriendelijke groet,<br>
   Sam Simons<br>
   Hoofdredacteur<br>";

  echo str_replace("<<abonnee>>","$abonnee","$brief"),(" 
 <<korting>>","$korting","$brief");
  ?>
```

Comment: Did you try giving it an array for each argument like the manual shows examples for? You can save yourself future delays by just bookmarking php.net and reading the pages for functions you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`str_replace()`](https://php.net/str_replace) using two arrays. The first for strings to replace, the second for the values. Note that the order should be the same.

```
$korting=50;
$abonnee="Jan Davids";

$brief="
Beste <b><<abonnee>></b><br>
U heeft het laatste nummer van ons magazine ontvangen.<br>
Omdat we u heel graag als abonnee willen behouden, bieden we u een
aantrekkelijke
en exclusieve korting: <br>U betaalt <<korting>> in plaats van 65
euro.
<br><br>
<i>Profiteer nu van deze aanbieding!</i><br><br>
Met vriendelijke groet,<br>
Sam Simons<br>
Hoofdredacteur<br>";

echo str_replace(["<<abonnee>>","<<korting>>"], [$abonnee,$korting], $brief);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo str_replace(
   ['<<abonnee>>','<<korting>>'],
   [$abonnee, $korting],
   $brief
);
```

It is always a good idea to look into a [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#refsect1-function.str-replace-examples).

Answer (score 2):

str_replace function accepts 2 arrays as parameters.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Therefore you can do the following usage to achieve what you expect:

```
    $search_array = array("<<abonnee>>", "<<korting>>");
    $replace_array   = array($abonnee,$korting);

    echo str_replace($search_array, $replace_array, $brief);
```